# spring security oauth client handling server redirect uri

Tags: spring-security

I'm new to Spring security oauth and now I want to set up an oauth 2.0 client with it.

I've spent much time studying the example project tonr2 and still don't understand how it response to server redirect url:

For example, when you register an application on google, it will ask you to provide a redirect url so that after your app successfully logged in, google will give you a code and redirect you to the url that you registered. The program listening on that url is suppose to exchange code for access token.

However I don't find a place to configure the redirect url in spring security oauth. If its not configurable, how does spring exchange code for access token?